# Attach ipv6 ip to a public network in vagrant

Tags: networking, vagrant, ipv6

Consider I have a vagrant machine with a public network.

```
ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::af55:3360:45cc:13ea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:37:f8:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12596  bytes 4067678 (3.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7706  bytes 4041830 (3.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.100.1.27  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.100.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe40:a0d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:40:a0:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20  bytes 6840 (6.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19  bytes 2550 (2.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I want to add an ipv6 ip to the public network interface. Is this possible in vagrant?

Final expected config:

```
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
    inet 192.100.1.27  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.100.1.255
    inet6 fe80::6f09:6698:1cc8:acab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2a00:81c0:6001:141::a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether fa:16:3e:19:aa:f4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1053729  bytes 358588297 (341.9 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 272053  bytes 62702710 (59.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a configuration I can set to achieve this. So I created a script that runs during vagrant provisioning that uses `nmcli` to add the ip to the interface. I am not sure if this is the best way to this, but it works.

```
echo "Setting network config for this node"

nmcli con add type ethernet ifname enp0s8 con-name public
nmcli con modify public ipv4.method manual +ipv4.addresses 192.100.1.27 
nmcli con modify public connection.autoconnect "yes"
nmcli con modify public +802-3-ethernet.mtu 1450
nmcli con modify public ipv6.method manual +ipv6.addresses 2a00:81c0:6001:141::a/64
nmcli con up public
```

I had to add this to the Vagrantfile.

```
c.vm.provision :shell, path: "path_to_script"
```